# Error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a pivot table here the code

```
SELECT 
    name, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
FROM 
    (SELECT name, pd, din 
     FROM [BLD].[dbo].[MC20$]) sq
PIVOT 
    (SUM(DIN) 
     FOR pd IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 
    ) AS pt
```

However I get this syntax error and can't find where the problem comes from:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Any guesses?

Thank you

Comment: `1` is not a valid SQL Server column name unquoted. You need to use `[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]` in both places

Comment: You need to surround the numbers with `[..]`. For example: `FOR pd IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])`

Answer (score 1):

You must use [delimited identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15) in the PIVOT statement, and in the SELECT list you use delimited identifiers to refer to the pivotted columns.  Otherwise you're selecting numeric literals.

```
SELECT <non-pivoted column>,  
    [first pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    [second pivoted column] AS <column name>,  
    ...  
    [last pivoted column] AS <column name>  
FROM  
    (<SELECT query that produces the data>)   
    AS <alias for the source query>  
PIVOT  
(  
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)  
FOR   
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])  
) AS <alias for the pivot table>  
<optional ORDER BY clause>;
```

[PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

But while the docs specify `[` and `]` these are just regular delimited identifiers and you can also use `"` if QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS is ON.

So should be:

```
SELECT name, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]
FROM (SELECT name,pd, din From  [BLD].[dbo].[MC20$]) sq
PIVOT 
( SUM(DIN) 
FOR pd IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]) 
) AS pt
```